# Spring security redirection after login

Tags: spring, spring-security

After successfull login, it doesn't redirects to "index.php". It redirects same page which is "login.php". Is there something wrong with my spring-security.xml page?

By the way when I run the application it redirects me to "login.php" which is good. But It doesn't shows primefaces components but html components. After I succesfully login, It redirects the same page but this time It shows Primefaces components instead of html components.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <form-login login-page='/pages/login.xhtml' default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"                    
                authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout.xhtml" />

</http>
<!--Authentication Manager Details -->    
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
<!--            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>-->
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

my web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

my login page

```
<p:outputPanel id="loginOutputPanelId" style="border: navy">
                        <p:panelGrid id="loginInformationPanel" columns="2">
                            <h:outputText value="Username: "/>
                            <p:inputText value="#{loginController.userName}"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Password: "/>
                            <p:inputText value="#{loginController.password}"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="Login" actionListener="#{loginController.login()}"/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
```

my loginController.login() method returns "index" string and my faces.config;

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

**EDIT:** 
without  component it runs without any problem. When i add form-login it says "The webpage at `http://localhost:8080/myApplication/pages/login.xhtml` has resulted in too many redirects".

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
<logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout.xhtml" />
<form-login login-page="/pages/login.xhtml"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
                default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"                                                        
                authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml"/>
</http>
```

My login page

```
<p:outputPanel id="loginOutputPanelId" style="border: navy">
                        <p:panelGrid id="loginInformationPanel" columns="2">
                            <h:outputText value="Kullanıcı Adı: "/>
                            <p:inputText id="j_username" required="true" value="#{loginController.userName}"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Şifre: "/>
                            <p:inputText id="j_password" required="true" value="#{loginController.password}"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton id="login" type="submit" ajax="false" value="Login" actionListener="#{loginController.login()}"/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
```

My new loginController.login() method;

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
         .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
         (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 16):

To force spring-security to go to `/pages/index.xhtml`, you can use property `always-use-default-target` as this :

```
<form-login login-page='/pages/login.xhtml' 
            default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"
            always-use-default-target="true"                    
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml"/>
```

Otherwise, the login page should be shown automatically by spring security when the user calls a secured resource, and once login done, continue to the secured resource it was originally asked for.

In your case, some confusion seems to come from the fact that you want spring security to handle the login, and you try to handle it yourself with a jsf actionListener and navigation rules.

putting "`<form-login [...]`" in the configuration essentially tells spring to activate a filter (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`) that will listen to requests made to `/j_spring_security_check` .  If you want spring to handle login, by default your form login must request this url, passing two parameters : `j_username` and `j_password` .

This way, spring's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` will kick in and try to authenticate the provided credentials using the UserDetailsService you configured in your AuthenticationProvider.

I think you have to remove your jsf controller for login and use spring-security to handle authentication.

Hope this helps.

PS : make sure your web.xml defines the DelegatingFilterProxy before all other servlet filters :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Still same. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: what is the first url you call ?  Do you directly call the login page or do you call another secured url ?

Comment: index.xhtml is my welcome file defined in "web.xml". I don't understand what you mean. There is login-page='/pages/login.xhtml' at spring-security.xml and spring security first calls login.xhtml. after I add always-use-default-target="true" line, now it doesn't redirects any page. It stays at login.xhtml page. Then I write index address manually to address bar of browser.

Comment: after I login I am getting Status report

message /myApplication/j_spring_security_check

description The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ***Faces Servlet*** URL pattern in `web.xml`.

If it contains `.jsf` like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then you must update your  code in spring-security.xml like:

```
<form-login login-page="/pages/login.jsf"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
            default-target-url="/pages/index.jsf"                                                        
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.jsf"/>
```